# Is there online corpus for the Chinese language?

Tags: simplified-characters, dictionary

Is there online corpus for the Chinese language? What I mean is something like the [Brown Corpus for American English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus).

Comment: Please clarify what kinds of queries you need to run. For instance, why wouldn't google meet your purposes (you can limit to Chinese results only)?

Comment: The primary disadvantage of the Google approach is that they don't have a search API and actively detect and block scraping. It would be suitable for any human needs, but probably not for what drobnbobn is after.

Answer (score 9):

For a big-data Chinese corpus, have a look at this one:

> [(Taiwan) Academia Sinica Balanced Corpus of Modern Chinese 台灣 中央研究院 中文詞知識庫小組 現代漢語平衡語料庫](http://rocling.iis.sinica.edu.tw/CKIP/engversion/20corpus.htm)

- A million-word level corpus
- Contact: Miss Su-Chu Lin (林素朱), jess@hp.iis.sinica.edu.tw
- [Introduction in Chinese](http://db1x.sinica.edu.tw/cgi-bin/kiwi/mkiwi/kiwi.sh?language=1)
- Not sure if you can download it for free

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found a large corpus, but I have used the results of some projects that analysed all Usenet newsgroups from 1993-1994. You could probably contact [Shih-Kun Huang](http://www.csie.nctu.edu.tw/~skhuang/) for information about the original corpus.

The files I used were a list of [character frequencies](http://technology.chtsai.org/charfreq/) and a list of [word frequencies](http://technology.chtsai.org/wordlist/).

It's probably smaller than you want, and it only contains individual sentences, but you might find the translations at [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show_all_in/cmn/none/none) interesting. You can download the [raw data](http://tatoeba.org/eng/downloads).

I don't know if they can be downloaded, but there are lots of example sentences on [jukuu.com](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%A5%BD).

Answer (score 3):

You can [download all of the Chinese language Wikipedia](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/zhwiki/latest/). (you would probably want: zhwiki-latest-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2)

Another source that may or may not be suitable depending on the specific project is [Project Gutenberg's collection of Chinese language books](http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/zh). The downside of this source is that most of them will be quite old.

Comment: What character set does the xml file use, traditional or simplified? If it is a mix, that's an issue.